# taking averages of counts relative to time

Tags: r

I am working on some bird data and need to figure out how to take the mean amount of time each birder spends out in the environment, and then from this take the mean of observation counts for that average time. Showing that on average, for this mean time you would expect to see this many observations.

Then I was also thinking of segmenting this for the duration of minutes. So, what are the mean observations for every 20 minute duration from 12:00am to 12:00pm.

I have tried this to get means of observation count relative to the duration minutes and times observations started:

```
aggregate(observation_count ~ duration_minutes + time_observations_started, ebird, mean)
```

But how do I order it as mentioned above? I realised that my code above misses out on many data values, it doesn't have all the time observations included, it also removes those that have zero values which I want to keep.

Reproducible code:

```
ebird <- structure(list(observer_id = c("obs34276", "obs3566", "obs134751", 
"obs122516", "obs174363", "obs176629", "obs94083", "obs215920", 
"obs115524", "obs34276", "obs134751", "obs221163", "obs1571", 
"obs44100", "obs133209", "obs175724", "obs34276", "obs34276", 
"obs134751", "obs221163", "obs221163", "obs221163", "obs33014", 
"obs118406", "obs223273", "obs108909", "obs1571", "obs34276", 
"obs14196", "obs134751", "obs134751", "obs115524", "obs102017", 
"obs223273", "obs38838", "obs223273", "obs115059", "obs157963", 
"obs94961", "obs223273", "obs223273", "obs212353", "obs223273", 
"obs38838", "obs122322", "obs94083", "obs223273", "obs35725", 
"obs35725", "obs34276", "obs34276", "obs136048", "obs132777", 
"obs136048", "obs223273", "obs223273", "obs223273", "obs223273", 
"obs223273", "obs223273", "obs157963", "obs40103", "obs157963", 
"obs33014", "obs115059", "obs124499", "obs205892", "obs175724", 
"obs117934", "obs223273", "obs163792", "obs144761", "obs218342", 
"obs223273", "obs108909", "obs223273", "obs108909", "obs148762", 
"obs108909", "obs223273", "obs33014", "obs223273", "obs223273", 
"obs175724", "obs337777", "obs146721", "obs217573", "obs7435", 
"obs120774", "obs148032", "obs209823", "obs230604", "obs156505", 
"obs156505", "obs163984", "obs156505", "obs156505", "obs156505", 
"obs156505", "obs156505"), observation_count = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), observation_date = structure(c(17050, 
14737, 14741, 14737, 14733, 14757, 14743, 14752, 14755, 14755, 
14758, 14786, 14735, 14735, 14735, 14739, 14732, 14733, 14779, 
14772, 14780, 14801, 14794, 14792, 14782, 14785, 14742, 14745, 
14837, 14839, 14846, 14755, 14765, 14756, 14780, 14767, 14851, 
14863, 14855, 14790, 14770, 14826, 14762, 14821, 14821, 14845, 
14764, 14777, 14777, 14863, 14864, 14867, 14874, 14875, 14773, 
14773, 14773, 14781, 14781, 14781, 14875, 14878, 14878, 14880, 
15100, 14868, 14758, 14870, 14882, 14777, 14880, 14730, 14758, 
14774, 14815, 14806, 14829, 14833, 14850, 14806, 14866, 14818, 
14777, 14880, 15880, 15101, 14731, 14730, 14735, 14743, 15095, 
15097, 14757, 14767, 14754, 14761, 14761, 14797, 14804, 14804
), class = "Date"), time_observations_started = structure(c(31380, 
36180, 30600, 47700, 29700, 27000, 45600, 32400, 24300, 30900, 
30600, 30600, 43800, 19800, 56700, 65640, 57300, 30300, 30600, 
55800, 30600, 39600, 60900, 25200, 27060, 23400, 47400, 24300, 
36300, 30600, 30600, 50100, 30900, 37440, 26100, 38100, 35100, 
35100, 33420, 38460, 36000, 56700, 37260, 28800, 28800, 37920, 
22440, 32880, 28680, 62700, 36900, 24600, 41700, 24600, 37320, 
25440, 27900, 25860, 36000, 25860, 27300, 53400, 19800, 37800, 
34200, 37800, 39600, 34200, 35100, 25800, 34200, 28800, 61200, 
33480, 31200, 33660, 38400, 40500, 46800, 33660, 60300, 22440, 
26220, 49800, 60900, 66000, 46800, 45000, 52200, 53100, 21600, 
54900, 24960, 24420, 50400, 29160, 36420, 35880, 24360, 36000
), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), duration_minutes = c(27, 
72, 240, 20, 90, 60, 20, 75, 3, 35, 210, 210, 30, 240, 25, 30, 
20, 15, 210, 90, 210, 180, 5, 15, 5, 60, 35, 30, 115, 210, 210, 
10, 25, 5, 105, 5, 70, 5, 10, 5, 5, 1, 5, 60, 105, 18, 5, 3, 
3, 35, 30, 30, 20, 30, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 40, 50, 3, 15, 90, 82, 
120, 5, 120, 5, 90, 210, 30, 5, 10, 5, 30, 30, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
40, 25, 50, 15, 10, 90, 120, 120, 60, 5, 5, 80, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: What did you try so far??

Comment: Thanks! Why don't you have `observer_id` (supposing that are the birders) at the RHS of your formula, don't you want to average on them?

Comment: You may want to include only the columns that are relevant to the question in the `dput`. Also maybe show expected output for first few rows?

Comment: @jay.sf You are right in pointing that out, however, I realised that it creates duplicate entries , so I opted for a more general perspective. Given the counts, and durations during particular periods, taking the means respective to one another. However, I realised that my code above misses out on many data values, it doesn't have all the time observations included, it also removes those that have zero values which I want to keep.

Comment: @Lime Aha. And `time_observations_started` denotes seconds since start of day?

Comment: it is in a hour-minutes-seconds format since midnight